# PlayOnLinux error on application when I change my timezone

Tags: wine, timezone

I have a game (scrolls.com) that I'm running under wine. Everything was OK, until I moved and changed my timezone.

Now, if I keep my old timezone it works. But if I change the timezone to something else, I get a black screen and the following error message:

```
[08/02/13 22:15:47] - Running wine-1.7.0 Scrolls.exe (Working directory : /home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/scrolls/drive_c/users/user/Local Settings/Application Data/Mojang/Scrolls)
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10ee8d0, overlapped 0x10ee8dc): stub
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias 240, std (d/m/y): 28/04/2013, dlt (d/m/y): 8/09/2013
wine: configuration in '/home/user/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/scrolls' has been updated.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias 240, std (d/m/y): 28/04/2013, dlt (d/m/y): 8/09/2013
Mono path[0] = 'C:/users/user/Local Settings/Application Data/Mojang/Scrolls/Scrolls_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'C:/users/user/Local Settings/Application Data/Mojang/Scrolls/Scrolls_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = 'C:/users/user/Local Settings/Application Data/Mojang/Scrolls/Scrolls_Data/Mono/etc'
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x20062, 0x1401c0): stub
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f768,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f0a8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:dxgi:dxgi_output_GetDesc iface 0x143388, desc 0x32f6a4 stub!
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0xf6b1d8e0, 0x1431e8, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0xf6b1d8e0
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32efb8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d9:wined3dformat_from_d3dformat Unhandled D3DFORMAT 0xffffffff
fixme:d3d9:wined3dformat_from_d3dformat Unhandled D3DFORMAT 0xffffffff
fixme:d3d9:wined3dformat_from_d3dformat Unhandled D3DFORMAT 0xffffffff
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table
fixme:d3d:query_init Unhandled query type 0xc.
fixme:win:RegisterRawInputDevices Unhandled flags 0x100 for device 0.
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x20062, filter=0x32fc6c,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:RegisterRawInputDevices Unhandled flags 0x100 for device 0.
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!
```

I read that the issue is due to a mismatch between the timezone in the registry, and the one in the computer. Strangely I tried to reinstall using the new timezone, but the problem persists.

How can I update the registry inside wine? and preferable using PlayOnLinux would be better.

**Edit**. Moreover, it seems that the problem is only with my new timezone (Santiago) as others seem to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

**a) start wine with a different TZ**

One solution would be to simply start wine with a different timezone each time (you probably want to update the shortcut in your start menu for example) using:

```
TZ=Europe/Berlin wine
```

**b) change the TZ in wine**

The registry of wine lies in `~/.wine` in the files `system.reg` (=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), `user.reg` (=HKEY_CURRENT_USER), `userdef.reg` (=HKEY_USERS) and is accessible by simply running `regedit` through wine (`wine regedit`).

The timezone key is in `Local Machine -> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` and can be set to any of the values that you see as directories at this place.

Comment: I see the key "Time Zones", but which value should I add?